# Import .txt into Array, output W/ Dialog boxes

Tags: java, arrays, methods, import, joptionpane

So I've been working on this code for awhile now and before adding the JOptionPane I tested it and there were 0 errors, then I added the JOptionPane and got between 27-38. So I clearly did something wrong in my JOptionPane but I'm not sure what, I only have experience using Scanner for the most part so any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScores
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String filename = ("scores.txt");
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        while (inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
            String line = inputFile.nextLine();
            ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
            scanner.useDelimiter(",");

            while(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                scores.add(scanner.nextInt());
            }

            scanner.close();
        }
    }

    public static int averageScore(int[] numbers) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i : numbers) {
            total += i;
        }
        return total/(numbers.length);
    }

    public static int modeOfScores(int[] numbers) {
        int modeCount = 0;
        int mode = 0;     
        int currCount = 0;    
        int currElement;

        for (int candidateMode : numbers) {
            currCount = 0;

            for (int element : numbers) {
                if (candidateMode == element) {
                    currCount++;
                }
            }

            if (currCount > modeCount) {
                modeCount = currCount;
                mode = candidateMode;
            }
        }

        return mode;
    }

    public static int lowestScore(int[] numbers) {
        int lowest = numbers[0];

        for(int i = 1; i > numbers.length; i++) {
            if(numbers[i] < lowest) {
                lowest = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return lowest;
    }

    public static int largestScore(int[] numbers) {  
        int largest = numbers[0];  
        for(int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {  
            if(numbers[i] > largest) {  
                largest = numbers[i];  
            }
        }  
        return largest;
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The Average number is: " + total);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The Mode number is: " + mode);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The Lowest number is: " + lowest);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The Largest number is: " + largest);
}
```

EDIT: Here are all the errors I got, all coming from the JOptionPane portion

```
TestScores.java:86: error: <identifier> expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Average number is: " +(averageScore));
                                ^
TestScores.java:86: error: illegal start of type
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Average number is: " +(averageScore));
                                 ^
TestScores.java:86: error: illegal start of type
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Average number is: " +(averageScore));
                                       ^
TestScores.java:86: error: ')' expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Average number is: " +(averageScore));
                                                                ^
TestScores.java:86: error: ';' expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Average number is: " +(averageScore));
                                                                  ^
TestScores.java:86: error: <identifier> expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Average number is: " +(averageScore));
                                                                               ^
TestScores.java:86: error: illegal start of type
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Average number is: " +(averageScore));
                                                                                ^
TestScores.java:86: error: <identifier> expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Average number is: " +(averageScore));
                                                                                 ^
TestScores.java:86: error: ';' expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Average number is: " +(averageScore));
                                                                                  ^
TestScores.java:87: error: illegal start of type
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Mode number is: " +(modeOfScores));
              ^
TestScores.java:87: error: illegal start of type
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Mode number is: " +(modeOfScores));
                                 ^
TestScores.java:87: error: illegal start of type
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Mode number is: " +(modeOfScores));
                                       ^
TestScores.java:87: error: ')' expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Mode number is: " +(modeOfScores));
                                                             ^
TestScores.java:87: error: ';' expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Mode number is: " +(modeOfScores));
                                                               ^
TestScores.java:87: error: <identifier> expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Mode number is: " +(modeOfScores));
                                                                            ^
TestScores.java:87: error: illegal start of type
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Mode number is: " +(modeOfScores));
                                                                             ^
TestScores.java:87: error: <identifier> expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Mode number is: " +(modeOfScores));
                                                                              ^
TestScores.java:87: error: ';' expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Mode number is: " +(modeOfScores));
                                                                               ^
TestScores.java:88: error: illegal start of type
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Lowest number is: " +(lowestScore));
              ^
TestScores.java:88: error: illegal start of type
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Lowest number is: " +(lowestScore));
                                 ^
TestScores.java:88: error: illegal start of type
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Lowest number is: " +(lowestScore));
                                       ^
TestScores.java:88: error: ')' expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Lowest number is: " +(lowestScore));
                                                               ^
TestScores.java:88: error: ';' expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Lowest number is: " +(lowestScore));
                                                                 ^
TestScores.java:88: error: <identifier> expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Lowest number is: " +(lowestScore));
                                                                             ^
TestScores.java:88: error: illegal start of type
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Lowest number is: " +(lowestScore));
                                                                              ^
TestScores.java:88: error: <identifier> expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Lowest number is: " +(lowestScore));
                                                                               ^
TestScores.java:88: error: ';' expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Lowest number is: " +(lowestScore));
                                                                                ^
TestScores.java:89: error: illegal start of type
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Largest number is: " +(largestScore));
              ^
TestScores.java:89: error: illegal start of type
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Largest number is: " +(largestScore));
                                 ^
TestScores.java:89: error: illegal start of type
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Largest number is: " +(largestScore));
                                       ^
TestScores.java:89: error: ')' expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Largest number is: " +(largestScore));
                                                                ^
TestScores.java:89: error: ';' expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Largest number is: " +(largestScore));
                                                                  ^
TestScores.java:89: error: <identifier> expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Largest number is: " +(largestScore));
                                                                               ^
TestScores.java:89: error: illegal start of type
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Largest number is: " +(largestScore));
                                                                                ^
TestScores.java:89: error: <identifier> expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Largest number is: " +(largestScore));
                                                                                 ^
TestScores.java:89: error: ';' expected
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Largest number is: " +(largestScore));
                                                                                  ^
TestScores.java:90: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
```

^

Comment: It's always helpful to include the errors/stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems, first. Your last 4 method calls are loose in the class.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Average number is: " +(total));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Mode number is: " +(mode));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Lowest number is: " +(lowest));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Largest number is: " +(largest));
```

They need to be inside a method in this case.

Second total, mode, lowest and largest are only locally defined within their respectively method scope.

You need to store them as members of TestScores.

Edit #1

*Small note, Java is written with lowerCamelCase http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase*

Edit #2

I went through the whole code and noticed quite a few misstakes.

1. An `array` in Java is not the same as an `ArrayList`. So you have to
   pick one, in this case an `ArrayList` will do the trick for you, as
   you can handle it more elegant.
2. `ArrayList` does not have indexes as an `array` has. Instead you have to use its method `get(index)`
   which is accessed by the `.` operator.
3. As the methods returns the values of `total`, `mode`, `lowest` and `largest` why not call them
   directly in your `showMessageDialog()`?

Edit #3

I don't have the `scores.txt` for testing right now. This gives no compilation errors.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScores
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException { 
        String filename = ("scores.txt");
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while (inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
            String line = inputFile.nextLine();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
            scanner.useDelimiter(",");

            while(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                scores.add(scanner.nextInt());
            }

            scanner.close();
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The Average number is: " + averageScore(scores));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The Mode number is: " + modeOfScores(scores));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The Lowest number is: " + lowestScore(scores));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The Largest number is: " + largestScore(scores));
    }

    public static int averageScore(List<Integer> numbers) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i : numbers) {
            total += i;
        }
        return total/(numbers.size());
    }

    public static int modeOfScores(List<Integer> numbers) {
        int modeCount = 0;
        int mode = 0;     
        int currCount = 0;    
        int currElement;

        for (int candidateMode : numbers) {
            currCount = 0;

            for (int element : numbers) {
                if (candidateMode == element) {
                    currCount++;
                }
            }

            if (currCount > modeCount) {
                modeCount = currCount;
                mode = candidateMode;
            }
        }

        return mode;
    }

    public static int lowestScore(List<Integer> numbers) {
        int lowest = numbers.get(0);

        for(int i = 1; i > numbers.size(); i++) {
            if(numbers.get(i) < lowest) {
                lowest = numbers.get(i);
            }
        }
        return lowest;
    }

    public static int largestScore(List<Integer> numbers) {  
        int largest = numbers.get(0);  
        for(int i = 1; i < numbers.size(); i++) {  
            if(numbers.get(i) > largest) {  
                largest = numbers.get(i);  
            }
        }  
        return largest;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much, i'll try playing around with what you've told me

Comment: @CobyBushong, I made an edit to your post to make it a bit more clear, there you can also see how normally curly brackets are placed.

Comment: I noticed other people doing that way, but I always thought it looked neater the way I did it, but thanks ill try to get used to placing them that way instead

Comment: okay i think i understand what you're saying in #3 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Average number is: " + (modeOfScores)); correct?? However, im not too sure i understand what you mean in #1 and #2

Comment: @CobyBushong almost! `modeOfScores()` is a method, remember the parentheses. It also takes an argument. In your original code it took an `int[]`, but your score is declared as a `List<Integer>` so change your methods and have `scores` as your input parameter.

Comment: haha I think I'm making things worse, It's not you I just don't understand, If you'd like I can edit my original with what I have now?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, just had a few little mistakes here and there! Have a great day :)